# How to auto responsive a page using px like using rem

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

when we use rem than we can auto controll full page size for responsive a page.

for example like:

```
div{
    font-size:20rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px)
{
    html{
        font-size:20%;
    }
}
```

**but when we use px than what can we do??**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `calc()` function in your stylesheet to calculate any value that you need. For example:

```
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

You might also want to check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) as well.

Comment: Thanks bro ! but i already used px. now what can i do ?